# Impossibility of Connecting Laravel with Pusher

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher, laravel-7

I'm testing the functionality of working with Laravel and Pusher, but when trying to send an event to Pusher I can't see it in the debug console.

This is a clean install, the keys / secret, cluster name are loaded correctly in the .env file

The steps I follow are: lift the application with `php artisan serve`, enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and it should send the event, I left it fixed in the file routes / web.php

I enter the Pusher website, tab "Debug console" and it doesn't track anything.

I leave a link to the repository, but it is a clean install, I just created the event and made the modification in the routes file.

https://github.com/cemansilla/Laravel-Websockets

Comment: Have you updated the .env file with the correct broadcast driver?

Comment: Yes, "BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher"